# Como selecionar vários dados de tabelas relacionadas

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, sql-select, tabela-banco-de-dados

Criei três tabelas no banco de dados aluno, livro e empréstimo, gostaria de listar todos os livros que foram emprestados a cada aluno, no entanto, quando o aluno pega mais de um livro emprestado o comando que eu uso para fazer a busca no banco só retorna um deles, e não todos os livros que foram emprestados aos alunos

Estrutura das tabelas

```
create table aluno(
Id_aluno smallint auto_increment,
Nome_aluno varchar(45) not null,
Cpf_aluno varchar(11) not null,
Curso_aluno varchar(45) not null,
primary key(Id_aluno)) default charset = utf8; -- Criando a tabela aluno
```

create table livro(
Id_livro smallint auto_increment,
Titulo_livro varchar(45) not null,
Editora_livro varchar(45),
Quant_livro smallint not null,
primary key(Id_livro)) default charset = utf8; -- criando a tabela de livro

create table emprestimo(
Id_emprestimo smallint not null,
Data_emprestimo Date not null,
Data_devolucao Date not null,
Id_aluno smallint,
Id_livro smallint,
primary key(Id_emprestimo),
foreign key(Id_aluno) references aluno(Id_aluno),
foreign key(Id_livro) references livro(Id_livro)) default charset = utf8; -- Cria a tabela de emprestimo que está refeenciada a tabela aluno e a tabela livro

Já o comando que eu estava usando para fazer a busca é o seguinte:

```
select Nome_aluno, Titulo_livro from emprestimo inner join aluno on aluno.Id_aluno = emprestimo.Id_emprestimo inner join livro on livro.Id_livro = emprestimo.Id_emprestimo;
```

Answer (score 1):

Essa consulta deve funcionar:

```
SELECT livro.Titulo_livro, aluno.Nome_aluno
FROM emprestimo JOIN livro ON emprestimo.Id_livro = livro.Id_livro
JOIN aluno ON emprestimo.Id_aluno = aluno.Id_aluno
```

O problema da sua consulta:

```
select Nome_aluno, Titulo_livro 
from emprestimo inner join aluno on aluno.Id_aluno = emprestimo.Id_emprestimo inner join livro on livro.Id_livro = emprestimo.Id_emprestimo;
```

é que você ta juntando as tabelas pelos atributos errados. Pelo o que você descreveu, você tem que juntar pelo atributo que às une, que são as chaves estrangeiras. Logo `aluno` tem que ser ligado à `emprestimo` por `Id_aluno` e não `Id_emprestimo`. Mesma coisa para livro.

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado cara!